# What is the 25th percentile option when transforming NaN values in a df?

Tags: python, pandas, transform, fillna

If I was to do a groupby fillna using median I understand that I would do the following:

```
df[cols].fillna(df.groupby(['year'])[cols].transform('median'))
```

However, if I want to fill with the 25th percentile instead, what would replace 'median'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.nanpercentile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanpercentile.html):

```
df[cols].fillna(df.groupby(["year"])[cols].transform(np.nanpercentile, q=25))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also avoid using numpy and use directly panda’s [`.quantile()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html)

```
df.groupby('year')[cols].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(.25))
```